# Save state button sharedpreferences Android

Tags: java, android, button, sharedpreferences

i've got a floatingbutoon (it's a button shortly), and when i click on it it starts a service and the button change icon. I tried in this way:

```
mFab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fabbutton);
mFab.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_play));
mFab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (RunService.isRunning) {
                    RunService.stopRun(MainActivity.this);
                    mFab.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_play));
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.mypck.asd", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", true);
                    editor.commit();

                } else {
                    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RunService.class));
                    mFab.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_pause));

                }
            }
        });
```

and to retrieve the state:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("com.mypck.asd", MODE_PRIVATE);
mFab.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", true));
```

But not working in this way because `setChecked` method is for a toggle button..Instead mine is a simple button! How can i solve?

Comment: do you want enable/disable the button depending on the value of the preference?

Comment: I would open the app and find the button at right state..so if i clicked the button `RunService.isRunning` i'm will aspected to find icon `R.drawable.ic_pause`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just save both state of button in `SharedPreference` like, **true** and **false** when Service is running or not in `if-else` condition

Look at below code.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.mypck.asd", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
if (RunService.isRunning) {
                RunService.stopRun(MainActivity.this);
                mFab.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_play));                   
                editor.putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", true);                    
            } else {
                startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RunService.class));
                mFab.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_pause));
               editor.putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", false);
            }
editor.commit();
```

**Update:**

To retrieving values you have to do like,

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("com.mypck.asd", MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean buttonState = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", true);

if(buttonState)
{
  mFab.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_play)); 
}else{
  mFab.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_pause));
}
```

replace

```
mFab.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_play));
```

with my above code.

Comment: Whats not working? As per your question you have now button's state both.

Comment: See my edit.. maybe the icon that i set as default could be create a problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok just save the state in your preference.

```
   mFab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.mypck.asd", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

                    if (RunService.isRunning) {
                        RunService.stopRun(MainActivity.this);
                        mFab.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_play));                        
                        editor.putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", true);
                    } else {
                       startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,RunService.class));    
                        mFab.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_pause));
                       editor.putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", false);
                    }
                    editor.commit();

                }
            });
```

Comment: Not works..but, see my edit i'm gonna make. The fab needs to have an icon setted. Maybe could be the problem?

Comment: @Elenasys - Is there any difference between yours and mine answer?